# Gsheets[Query and IF] not retrieving the values referenced from a common cell value (a drop down)

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where a series of scores by dates, and dropdown selector as Q1 to Q4.
Now, I am creating the output based on the Selector i.e Q1 or Q2 or Q3 etc, by the following function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60CBp.png)

But the result is always the same even choosing the other values from the dropdown. Please advise if this formula is correct.

=IFS(H17="Q1", QUERY(A17:E20, "select C where B  > '01/01/2023' and B <= '03/31/23'",1), H17="Q2", QUERY(A17:E20, "select C where B  > '03/31/2023' and B <= '06/30/23'",1),
H17="Q3", QUERY(A17:E20, "select C where B  > '30/06/2023' and B <= '30/09/23'",1))

Always the result is the first value in the row i.e "1"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your expected output is, but your dates are not formatted properly. Here's the corrected date formatting:

```
=IFS(H17="Q1", QUERY(A17:E20, "select C where B > date '2023-01-01' and B <= date '2023-03-31'",1), H17="Q2", QUERY(A17:E20, "select C where B > date '2023-03-31' and B <= date '2023-06-30'",1), H17="Q3", QUERY(A17:E20, "select C where B > date '2023-06-30' and B <= date '2023-09-30'",1))
```

Edit:

You had a few more issues with your formula.

- Since you're using 1 as the last parameter of the QUERY function, it is interpreting it as the header row count, which is why you're always getting the value of 1. You can adjust the QUERY function by removing the last parameter and use date format in the condition.
- The QUERY function is returning an array of results rather than a single value. You can use the ARRAYFORMULA function to process the array and return a single value.

```
=IFS(H17="Q1", INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(A17:E20, "select C where B > date '2023-01-01' and B <= date '2023-03-31'")),1), H17="Q2", INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(A17:E20, "select C where B > date '2023-03-31' and B <= date '2023-06-30'")),1), H17="Q3", INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(A17:E20, "select C where B > date '2023-06-30' and B <= date '2023-09-30'")),1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I am expecting col C based on the selector Q1/Q2 etc. i have copied your formula, but still its not retrieving the value of the score 1.

Comment: What output are you expecting for each of the dropdown options?  Also you have inconsistent dates in your formula. For example you have `03/31/23` as well as `30/09/23`.

Comment: I am expecting as follows, when i choose Q2 in the drop down, then i need the output as 2 from col C18 based on the date in col B as its in April, if i choose Q3 then i need C19 as its in July.

Comment: I updated the answer with some fixes